# Should the header and footer tags be inside the main tag

Tags: html

I'm using the `main` tag - should I put my header and footer tags inside the main tag or should they be separate?

Also, does the main tag need role="main"?

Comment: Checkout http://html5doctor.com/the-main-element/

Comment: That depends whether they are the header and footer of the specific page's content (yes) or of the website (not)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since it represents the central part of your page - the "beef" if you want - and headers and footers are considered adjacent content, I would argue that headers and footers should not be child elements.

In theory, yes, using `<main>` does mean the same as adding `role="main"`. But as it has limited support at the moment, using `<main role="main">` [is recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: You should never use the `role=` attribute on an element with the same name. This attribute is used for assistive technologies and elements that already have that name are automatically associated with the role. So don't ever put `<footer role="footer">` or `<main role="main">` it's pointless and considered bad practice.

Answer (score 73):

From HTML5doctor article [The main element](http://html5doctor.com/the-main-element/) @Gaby aka G. Petrioli

### tl;dr

Rule of thumb :

- only one `<main>` per page ;
- top-level element (in most cases) ;
- don't put your site's header/menu/footer (repeated content) in your `<main>`.
- can hold article header/footer *if specific*.

### Purpose

> The primary purpose of <main> is to map ARIA’s landmark role main** to
>   an element in HTML. This will help screen readers and other assistive
>   technologies understand where the main content begins. The W3C spec
>   describes  as representing:

#### Specs says

Here is what [the draft spec says](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-main-element):

> The main content area consists of content that is directly related to
>   or expands upon the central topic of a document or central
>   functionality of an application.

#### Header/footer

[**Exclude** site's header/footer/menu](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-main-element):

> *excludes content that is repeated across a set of documents* such as
>   site navigation links, copyright information, site logos and banners
>   and search forms (unless the document or applications main function is
>   that of a search form).

### Continue to use `role='main'`

But as a side note to this article Steve Faulkner write:

> You should still use the ARIA role until all browsers map the role to
>   the <main> element.

Comment: thanks for the info, this leaves it very clear, I want to use a header element inside my main element to describe the header for the main content only, (I already have another header tag for the body where my top nav is), it seems that this shouldn't create and issue and will help to be more specific, thanks, best answer!

Answer (score 5):

Check out the spec, it has a pretty good explanation on it: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-main-element

> Authors must not include the main element as a descendant of an article, aside, footer, header or nav elem

The spec only mentions that `main` can not be nested into any of the mentioned elements, but doesn't say anything about the other way around. I'd say, that the `header` and `footer` should be completely separate from the `main` in most cases. `main` holds your "main content", and the header and footer is usually separate from that.

As for the ARIA-role, it should be implicit, but for the time being, it is recommended that you give it the role manually. As the spec says:

> Authors are advised to use ARIA role="main" attribute on the main element until user agents implement the required role mapping.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to interpret semantics, but I would recommend to use header and footer as separated elements not within the main tag, but in between.

```
<header></header>
<main role="main"></main>
<footer></footer>
```

But I believe that your way of wanting to do it wouldn't be wrong either.

```
<main role="main">
<header></header>
<footer></footer>
</main>
```